# 404 Error shown while clicking on STS installation link from official spring website

Tags: spring-boot, installation, sts

I am trying to install STS Spring Tool Suit from their official website. But when clicked on provided link, the 404 error is shown. I am using google chrome as browser.
What i tried is:
Try 1: checked for sts download link in official website
Try 2: Checked sts github repository . But that link also showing 404 error :
"status": 404,
"message": "children items not found on all virtual repos"